# ¿Es recomendable castear el tipo de dato al asignar memoria dinámica?

Tags: c

Dada la siguiente estructura:

```
struct Person {
   const char *nombre;
   char edad;
   double sueldo;
}
```

Para crear un objeto dinámico de tipo `Person` he visto hacerlo de dos formas:

1. Casteando el puntero devuelto por `malloc()` al tipo `Person`

```
struct Person *p_person = (struct Person*)malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
```

2. Sin castear el puntero devuelto por `malloc()`

```
struct Person *p_person = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
```

Mi pregunta es ¿Qué ventajas tiene una sobre la otra y cuál es la más recomendable?

Gracias!

Comment: Si fueras a buscar ventajas, en la segunda escribes menos. La primera es una curita que necesitas si estas escribiendo C en un compilador de C++, ya que C permite la conversion implicita de `void*` a cualquier `T*`, pero C++ no. La mas recomendable en mi opinión seria la segunda.

Comment: Genial, entonces usaré la versión simplificada porque no pienso pasarme a C++. Muchas gracias bro!